# Changing the color of each item of a list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Runn` that has the boolean field `occupied`. My goal is to list the ids of each `Runn` in a `Ward`, displaying the occupied `Runns` in Green and the empty `Runns` in red. Currently I have

```
<p>
  <strong>List of Runns (ids)</strong>
  <%= @ward.runns.ids %>
</p>
```

how do I access each individual `runn` to compare their `occupied` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through them. I'm not sure how you want to tell whether it's 'occupied' or 'empty' - replace `r.occupied?` in the example below with your check.

```
<p>
  <strong>List of Runns (ids)</strong>
  <% @ward.runns.each do |r| %>
    <span style="color: <%= r.occupied? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
      <%= r.id %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give different class based on the `boolean` field as below:

```
<p>
  <strong>List of Runns (ids)</strong>
  <% @ward.runns.each do |r| %>
    <span class="<%= r.occupied? ? 'runn-occupied' : 'runn-empty' %>">
      <%= r.id %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

And in you `css` file, add different style for them (color, margin, size...):

```
.runn-occupied{
  background-color: green;
}
.runn-empty{
  background-color: red;
}
```